# Can't mix specification with fmt library

Tags: c++, fmt

With fmt library (or std::format) I can do formatting like in the example below

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    double x = 2.0/3.0;
    fmt::print("{:*^30}\n", x); //print ******0.6666666666666666******
    fmt::print("{:+.3e}\n", x); //print +6.667e-01
 }
```

In the above code, I can:

- Use the first formatting to center x and pad with *.
- Use the second formatting to format x in scientific notation with 3 decimal places and a +.

How can I combine both of these to get this?

```
**********+6.667e-01**********
```

Answer (score 2):

The [standard format specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter) for basic types and strings is:

> fill-and-align(optional) sign(optional) #(optional) 0(optional) width(optional) precision(optional) L(optional) type(optional)

This would lead me to think that your desired format specification is

```
fmt::print("{:*^+30.3e}\n", x);
```